how to process bigtable join with pyflink
There are two tables A and B in PostgreSQL, both of which have approximately tens of millions or billions of records. I want to use the batch mode of PyFlink to process the join results of these two tables. Can I use only one join statement to query? Or is there another way?
query sql like this:
select A.col1,A.col2,B.col1,B.col2 from A join B on A.col3=b.col3
where A.col4>'2024-01-01' and A.col4<'2024-07-01' and B.col4 is not null

